how to train and hypertune a model
As I am new to machine learning, and learning it myself, pardon me if I ask a silly question. My question is: What is the correct approach to building a model for, say, random forest and tuning hyperparameters? Should we need to set a random state, or do we need to see how it is performing on different subsets of the training data by not setting the random state and then by seeing low bias and low variance in from r2, we set the random state for one desired model for result reproducibility.   Or we first set the random state and then set hyperparameters, seeing the r2 value of the model and on testing set and then finalize the best hyperparameters and then remove the random state and see whether it is consistent over different subsets and then again apply the random state for the final model.   It is very confusing; please help me in understanding it.

Setting the random state is a tool for

Preventing you from chasing small differences in the validation outcomes
Making sure other researchers can reproduce your result exactly

Second one is more important. I would fix the random state at first to achieve goal one. Then before you're publishing or while doing the research, definitely try out a few others to make sure you haven't fooled yourself. If you have enough data and the cross validation is setup correctly, these variations shouldn't lead to any material differences. Then, when sharing your results, include a fixed random seed to make sure others can follow along.
This is not a silly question and there will be other interpretations and opinions on the topic! Using a random state is good practice. However, as you're just starting out, you can also ignore the whole thing. It's much less important than getting other things right such as the train-test-validation splitting and the cross validation. And not leaking data.

I don't have enough data. I have only 105 data points, out of which I removed outliers, and only 95 data points left. In this, I have two feature variables and one target variable. The data has very high variance, i ran Monte carlo and the variation in r2 on test set range from from 0.27 to 0.57. but les variance on training set it is from 0.62 to 0.65.   These results are without random state. Numbers may change but low bias high variance remains.

Cross-validation R^2 scores on training set: [0.46008804 0.20843573 0.40781263 0.17306629 0.61512692]
Mean CV R^2 score on training set: 0.3729059224101773
R^2 Score on training set: 0.8359541244860245
R^2 Score on test set: 0.8162437622141088  the values given above are the values of evalution metrics for only one run with random state, but when i remove the random state, results vary so much

Ok, with a dataset this small, you will indeed get higher bias in the evaluation. What is your question?
